# isolate key value pairs in array of objects that have null value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a new object that contains all of the key/value pairs from an object where the values are null.  Here is the code thus far -

```js
    const d = { pp: 1700, no: 2300, co: null, ng: 4550, zx: null };
    const nulls = {};

    Object.entries(d).forEach(([k, v]) => v === null ? nulls[k]: v);
    console.log(nulls);
```

The desired outcome is that the `nulls` object contains `{ co: null, zx: null }`; however, the code above causes `nulls` to be an empty object.

What needs to be modified to get the necessary output?  Maybe there is a more concise approach...possibly using `.filter()`?

Comment: `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(d).filter(([,v]) => v === null));`. But in your `forEach` you're just failing to assign to the `k`. `v === null && nulls[k] = v);`

Comment: Just modify the condition in the dupe target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned `filter` is a possible approach and after that convert back to an object using `Object.fromEntries`

```js
const d = { pp: 1700, no: 2300, co: null, ng: 4550, zx: null };


const res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(d).filter(([k,v]) => v===null))
console.log(res)
```

possible solution using `reduce`

```js
 const d = { pp: 1700, no: 2300, co: null, ng: 4550, zx: null };


 const res = Object.entries(d).reduce((acc,[k,v])=> {
  if(v===null)acc[k]=v
  return acc
 },{})
 
 console.log(res)
```

Comment: @pilchard I'm curious how reduce could be used to convert it back to an object.  Would you like to post an answer which demonstrates that?

Comment: This type of question has been asked multiple times on SO. Please close these questions as duplicate instead of adding yet another copy of an already written answer...

Comment: I had difficulty finding a similar question; thus the post.  Do you have a specific link to a post that is essentially the same as this question?

Comment: @knot22 The dupe target which I've used to close the question... o.O

Comment: Apologies.  I did not understand what was meant by "dupe target" when I read your comment under my original post.  Your comment immediately above adds the missing context to understand what that meant.